# Avoiding the use of global vars in this situation

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I wrote this "code" to show the problem since the actual code is quite big

```
(defn add-list
  ([number]

  (def used [number])
  (add-list number used))

  ([number used]

   ;Add elements to used
   ;Process the elements in used
   ;Find the next number

   (add-list number used)
   ))
```

I need to have a vector that I can access in the fn that will allow me to process the items inside the vector and then add the output to the vector so that the old items and the new items are in this vector for the next cycle.

I got it working by defining the vector above the add-list function but if I run the program on repl a second time the vector doesn't get cleared. It also says the vector is unbound sometimes.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the code needs to do. You may also wish to review the `reduce` function for accumulating results: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce

Comment: I'm not adding numbers I'm just trying to pass a vector of items into this loop that will be adding to the vector based on the current contents.

Comment: I've been getting it to work unreliably using the above style but i get errors such this: IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound

Comment: The code is faulty. `(add-list 3)` produces `StackOverflowError`, since the arity-2 function is effectively `(defn add-list [number used] (add-list number used))`, which is an inescapable recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function can be used to accumulate a list of results, not just sum values:

```
(defn accum-reverse
  [cum-state curr-val]
  (cons curr-val cum-state))

(println
  (reduce accum-reverse
    []              ; initial value of cum-state
    [1 2 3 4 5]     ; fed into curr-val one at a time
  ))

;=> (5 4 3 2 1)
```

The function `accum-reverse` is called 5 times. The first time `cum-state` is the initial value of `[]`, the empty vector. Each subsequent time `cum-state` is set to the previous return value from`accum-reverse`.

Besides the online docs, you can also get some good information from [Clojure for the Brave & True](http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/). Most of it is online, but it is also worth a purchase.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have currently is that I'm trying to update data in a vector from the loop but the loop isn't getting the updated data only the initial data in the following cycles. I know I'm updating it properly, the vector is defined outside the loop

Comment: I cant seem to find a way to give every recursive loop the latest data

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `accum-reverse` is a lot like `conj`, if you use `()` as your initial value instead of `[]`.

Comment: @MDubzem, as Alan has noted, each time you are in the `accum-reverse` function the first argument to the function is `cum-state` which holds all of the values resulting from each iteration. So in the example above, after 2 iterations, `cum-state` will have `[5 4]`. That is the new value list. If you wanted to have both old and new you have two choices: 1) Take the results of the `reduce` and put together with the old values in a new data structure, or 2) Create the hypbrid structure with old and `will be new` structure as the initial value to the reduce.